# How to check if somebody else is signing to my Yahoo account

Tags: security, gmail, outlook.com, yahoo-mail

I have Hotmail/Yahoo/GMail email accounts. How to check if somebody else is logging in to my email accounts? I mean Sometimes I send offline message to my Yahoo Messenger but when I log in to my yahoo account it doesn't show the offline messages in my Yahoo (new Yahoo mail UI).

Answer (score 4):

One thing you might be able to do is to sign up for a second account on the service, add your first account as a buddy, then wait for it to show up online regardless of you not being signed in on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to do so. Usually my Messenger profile is invisible to everybody. Lately I don't use my messenger that much but I am not receiving the offline messages that sent to my self. I mean I accidentally noticed that today.

Answer (score 4):

If you suspect someone is logging into your accounts, you should change your passwords on these accounts as soon as possible.

But before you change your password, go into the accounts and make sure that email is not being forwarded onto any other email addresses that are not your own. It is common for a compromised account to have had the settings changed so that any emails are forwarded onto a third party.

For example, on Google Mail go to "Mail Settings", then "Forwarding and POP/IMAP", If you always log into Google to get your mail, then all the settings on this page would normally be disabled. Disable the relevant options and try sending your emails again.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to know if somebody else is accessing for sure. Anyway, I have changed the password but I still really curious if it possible to know if somebody else is actually accessing my emails...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the others but Gmail will tell you your recent activity. There should be link at the bottom with text like this:

```
Last account activity: 45 minutes ago on this computer.  Details
```

The details link will open a pop up that will have the IP address and timestamp for your last few logins. There's also an option to add a secondary login credential for gmail if you're really paranoid: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-secure-cloud-for-millions-of.html

Comment: Also suggest skimming this for Gmail: http://www.friedbeef.com/how-to-check-if-your-gmail-account-has-been-hacked/

Comment: Why do people up-vote an answer like this that doesn't answer the question? @dgine clearly speaks of Yahoo.

Answer (score 2):

- After logging into your yahoo account, go to your "Account Information" page from the top right (below your name);
- You will be again asked for your password. When the page opens, click on the link "View your recent sign-in activity" under **Sign-In and Security** section;
- A new page will be opened, on which you can view the details of signing 'time', 'date', 'location' and 'type of login';
- And after you find any kind of misbehavior with your account, you can contact the Customer Care (below on the same page).

I hope it is helpful to you.